# How to transfer ERC1155 token using web3js?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, nft

I am trying to transfer ERC1155 tokens to another account. I have deployed the contract and have put down my contract code below.
The problem I am facing is I get the below error when I call `getMyToken` function from my frontend web3js code.

```
{code: -32603, message: 'execution reverted: ERC1155: caller is not owner nor approved', data: {…}}
```

Not sure what is happening. I am calling the function as below from frontend. The `isApproved` function is returning true.

```
const selectedAccountIsApproved = await monkeysContract.methods.isApproved(selectedAccount).call();
console.log('IS APPROVED RESULT: ', selectedAccountIsApproved);
if(selectedAccountIsApproved) {
    const result = await monkeysContract.methods.mintMyMonkey(selectedAccount, 0).call();
    console.log('Transfer Result: ', result);
} else {
    console.log('Account not approved by owner for transfers');
}
```

NOTE:

1. I have called the `setApprovalForAll` method and approved the receiver account.
2. I am able to call `isApprovedForAll` and verify that the account is approved.
3. I am able to transfer tokens to the receiver through Etherscan contract interface.

Contract Code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Monkeys is ERC1155, Ownable {
    uint256 public constant CC1 = 0;
    uint256 public constant CC2 = 1;

    mapping (uint256 => string) private _uris;

    constructor() public ERC1155("https://game.example/api/item/{id}.json") {
        _mint(msg.sender, CC1, 1000, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, CC2, 1000, "");
    }

    function uri(uint256 tokenId) override public view returns (string memory) {
        return(_uris[tokenId]);
    }
    
    function setTokenUri(uint256 id, string memory url) public onlyOwner {
        require(bytes(_uris[id]).length == 0, "Cannot set uri twice"); 
        _uris[id] = url; 
    }

    function transfer(address from, address to, uint256 id, uint256 amount, bytes memory data) public {
        safeTransferFrom(from, to, id, amount, data);
    }

    function isApproved(address user) public view virtual returns (bool) {
        return isApprovedForAll(owner(), user);
    }

    function getMyToken(address to, uint256 id) public {
        transfer(owner(), to, id, 1, 'test');
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `selectedAccount` the same with the address you used to send the call? The transfer method check if the `msg.sender` is the same with the `from` address or from list of approved for `owner()`